# data science / machine learning resources?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request

In a few weeks I'm starting a new job that will be involved in machine learning and data science.

I have a masters degree in probability / mathematics but I have no knowledge of machine learning and data science.

Are there any online resources like courses or books that could help me prepare for my new job? Basically I'm trying to get a head start on my new job.

Right now the only things I really know related to this fields are regression methods like linear regression and logistic regression, and I have a decent grasp of mathematical concepts so I'd prefer something that is not totally dumbed-down

Answer (score 12):

Start with the [Coursera's Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) course. It does a really good job in introducing the student to the domain of Machine Learning and helps you lay a solid foundation in the concepts.

In case, you feel that the math is a bit dumbed down in that course, you can take [this course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599), taught by the same professor and is more math-intensive than the former.

Now, you would have a clear intuition about the basic concepts of Machine Learning. Take [this course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD63A284B7615313A), which can be said as a follow-up or a supplement to the course of Andrew Ng.

[This resource from IAPR](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/IAPR/researchers/MLPAGES/mltut.htm) has in-depth notes on a lot of ML concepts like cross-validation, regularization, etc.

You can also have a look at these [amazing list of resources](https://www.quora.com/profile/Eren-Golge/Machine-Learning/Some-of-useful-machine-learning-resources-from-beginner-to-intermediate) compiled into a blog on Quora.

Now, for diving into advanced concepts of neural networks and deep learning, you can make use of [this free book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/).

Finally, the free e-book: [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) is a wonderful book for beginners in ML or Statistical Learning.

Comment: thanks!
is there any way to read the 1st link's material without enrolling and waiting for it to be posted?

Comment: Yes, you can watch the videos from the archive [here](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/preview)