# Should i pick this as a career?

Tags: bigdata, predictive-modeling, beginner

I'm mainly interested in creative things, but also interested in the science behind viewership and marketing a piece of media. Think about having a stable career in data science, where do you think I should begin? Are media analytics as big as others like business intelligence? Ive checked online courses, like google analytics academy and others like these:

https://www.edx.org/xseries/data-science-analytics-context

https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhudatascience

Is this the right path to take? And is it easy to find jobs in such a field even if the person is a beginner in programming?

Comment: As said by sb0709, Just keep in mind that there is no magic; you should learn about modeling, programming, math and statistics so computers do not do anything out of nothing for you. However, it is worth giving it a try. Any of the courses you mentioned are good. You can enroll for free, get involved in learning and see how you feel. Good luck

Comment: That's a nice advice from @HamidehIraj. In case you want to pursue, you can have a look at [this](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8963/11097). But, the decision is yours to make, and thus the close vote from my side as _opinion based_. Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Data Science is all about creativity and do/see things what makes sense.

I would describe Data Scientist career in couple words: Take this path only and only if you are passionate about science, working with data and are curious. Do not take this way if you are thinking about money or job security ... this field is not so simple and you stay weeks and months experimenting and try to find something in that datasets ... 
One example: as data scientist you are mostly starting to look at data and try to find something inside and solve problems, some dta does not provide any info and after weeks of "magic" is put on the side and moved to other project, after a while you returning and look into data to find information on other business problems.

Look at Data Science as pure science and only after that about money, also most of the data scientist's primary goal is not remuneration ... media is promoting salaries but not the real work what we doing ... how much we love data ...